# Graphical placeholder for "variables"

Tags: math-mode, boxes

### Question

The image below exactly shows what I am trying to accomplish in LaTeX.

[image: 3 + _ = 7?]

#### Research

- Using `\fbox` (as [Peter Grill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill) suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47062/38074)):

  ```
  \documentclass[]{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}

  \begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\Y}{\textbf{\fbox{?}}}%

  \[3 + \Y = 7\]

  \end{document}
  ```

  I thought of replacing the question mark by a space and then removing the top border, but I have not found any material on how to hide specific borders.
- Using `\fcolorbox`:

  Again, I do not know how to hide the top border.
- Using `mdframed`:

  This does not work in math mode as far as I know.

---

### Small improvement to Donut E. Knot's post (former accepted answer)

Donut E. Knot's post perfectly answered the question, however, I want to provide a small improvement which is too small for an own answer, but still too useful for being lost in a comment.

Add the following code under Knot's code:

```
\newdimen{\phWidth}%    
\newcommand\phAutoWidth[1]{%
    \setlength{\phWidth}{\widthof{#1}}%
    \ph[\phWidth]{#1}}
```

You now no longer need to explictly specify a width, instead, it will be automatically computed.

Comment: `\rule` can do the job.

Comment: You may like to have a look at [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/4918) ;-)

Comment: @Tobi Thanks for the link! I updated my question. One question though: does the same apply for single dollar signs (`$ ...$`)?

Comment: Hm … the problem with single `$`’s is not that big, while `\( … \)` is the LaTeX syntax, `$ … $` should render the same (which not applies for the `\[\]`-`$$` style – as you know) … see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/4918

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a TikZ based solution working for math and text.

[image: teaser]

### Usage

Use `\fib{<text/math>}` to create a fill in box. Use the starred version to show the solution of a single box or `\fibhideanswerfalse` to show all solutions. With `\tikzset{fill in/.style={<box style>}}` or `\tikzset{<underline/bracket> style/.style={<drawing style>}}` the style can be changed globally or with `\fib[underlined box]{<text/math>` for a single box.

### Examples

```
A \fib{short} example with math $1 + 2^{\fib{2}} = \fib{5} = \sqrt{25}$.
```

[image: colored box 1]

[image: colored box with answers]

[image: colored box 2]

[image: framed box]

[image: underlined box]

[image: dotted underlined box]

[image: underbracked box]

[image: colored underbracket box]

[image: underoverbracked box]

### `beamer` class

One can use the following to have one slide with the empty boxes and the next one with the solutions on it.

```
\begin{frame}{Beamer example}
   \only<2->{\fibhideanswerfalse}
   A \fib{short} example with math $1 + 2^{\fib{2}} = \fib{5} = \sqrt{25}$.
\end{frame}
```

Or use the following to show the answers step by step.

```
\begin{frame}{Beamer example}
   A \fib<2->{short} example with math $1 + 2^{\fib<3->{2}} = \fib<4->{5} = \sqrt{25}$.
\end{frame}
```

### Code

<sub>There’s also a german explanation in my blog: [TeX-Beispiel der Monats: Lückentexte](http://tobiw.de/tbdm/lueckentexte).</sub>

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
%\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newlength\fib@width
\def\fib@widthfactor{1.75}
\newif\iffibhideanswer
\fibhideanswertrue
\tikzset{
   every fill in box/.style={
     inner xsep=0pt,
     minimum height=3ex,
     align=center,
     font={\sffamily\slshape},
   },
   colored box/.style={
      every fill in box,
      fill=yellow!50!white,
   },
   framed box/.style={
      every fill in box,
      draw,
   },
   underline style/.style={},
   underlined box/.style={
      every fill in box,
      append after command={%
         \pgfextra{\begin{pgfinterruptpath}
            \draw [underline style] (\tikzlastnode.south west)
                  -- (\tikzlastnode.south east);
         \end{pgfinterruptpath}}
      },
   },
   bracket style/.style={},
   underbracked box/.style={
      every fill in box,
      append after command={%
         \pgfextra{\begin{pgfinterruptpath}
            \draw [bracket style] ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0,2pt)$)
                  |- (\tikzlastnode.south)
                  -| ($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(0,2pt)$);
         \end{pgfinterruptpath}}
      },
   },
   underoverbracked box/.style={
      every fill in box,
      append after command={%
         \pgfextra{\begin{pgfinterruptpath}
            \draw [bracket style] ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)-(0,2pt)$)
                  |- (\tikzlastnode.north)
                  -| ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)-(0,2pt)$);
            \draw [bracket style] ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0,2pt)$)
                  |- (\tikzlastnode.south)
                  -| ($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(0,2pt)$);
         \end{pgfinterruptpath}}
      },
   },
   fill in/.style={
      colored box,
   },
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \fib@hide } { m } {%
   \iffibhideanswer
      \phantom{#1}%
   \else
      #1%
   \fi
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \fib@makebox }{ m }{%
   \settowidth{\fib@width}{\tikz\node[fill in]{#1};}%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(fill in node.base)]
      \node (fill in node) [text width=\fib@widthfactor*\fib@width,fill in] {%
         \fib@hide{#1}%
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \fib } { s d{<}{>} o m }{{%
   \IfBooleanT{#1}{\fibhideanswerfalse}%
   \IfValueT{#2}{\only<#2>{\fibhideanswerfalse}}%
   \IfValueT{#3}{\tikzset{fill in/.style={#3}}}%
   \ifmmode
      \mathchoice
         {\fib@makebox{$\displaystyle#4$}}
         {\fib@makebox{$\textstyle#4$}}
         {\fib@makebox{$\scriptstyle#4$}}
         {\fib@makebox{$\scriptscriptstyle#4$}}
   \else
      \fib@makebox{#4}%
   \fi
   \IfValueT{#2}{}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% STYLE SETTING EXAMPLES
%\tikzset{colored box/.append style={fill=black!15}}
%\tikzset{fill in/.style={framed box}}
%\tikzset{fill in/.style={underlined box}}
%\tikzset{underline style/.style={densely dotted,thick}}
%\tikzset{fill in/.style={underbracked box}}
%\tikzset{fill in/.style={underoverbracked box}}
%\tikzset{bracket style/.style={gray,thick}}
%\fibhideanswerfalse


% ARTICLE/BOOK EXAMPLES
A \fib{short} example with math $1 + 2^{\fib{2}} = \fib{5} = \sqrt{25}$.

\vspace{2cm}
In \fib{text} mode and math $1 + 3 = \fib{4} = \fib{\frac{8}{2}}$
\begin{equation}
   1 + 3 = \fib{4} = \fib{\frac{8}{2}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
   (a + b)^2 = \fib{a^2 + 2ab + b^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
   \begin{pmatrix}
      1 \\ 2 \\ 3
   \end{pmatrix}
   \times
   \begin{pmatrix}
      4 \\ 5 \\ 6
   \end{pmatrix}
   =
   \fib{\begin{pmatrix}
      -3 \\ 6 \\ -3
   \end{pmatrix}}
\end{equation}
With an asterisk, i.e. \verb+\fib*+, the \fib*{solution} is always visible.
The optional argument can be used to change \fib*[underlined box]{styles} locally.


% BEAMER EXAMPLES
%\begin{frame}{Beamer example 1}
%   \only<2->{\fibhideanswerfalse}
%   A \fib{short} example with math $1 + 2^{\fib{2}} = \fib{5} =
%   \sqrt{25}$.
%\end{frame}
%\begin{frame}{Beamer example 2}
%   A \fib<2->{short} example with math $1 + 2^{\fib<3->{2}} =
%   \fib<4->{5} = \sqrt{25}$.
%\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Implementation overview

For the implementation we need [`tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) (with the `calc` library) and [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to implement the fill in boxes. I load [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) for the `{pmatrix}` example …

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

Next step is to make `@` available for internal command names.

```
\makeatletter
```

Then I define a new width, which will measure the width of the box, a factor to stretching the natural width (hand writing needs more space than printing) and an switch to show or hide the solutions (default: hide):

```
\newlength\fib@width
\def\fib@widthfactor{1.75}
\newif\iffibhideanswer
\fibhideanswertrue
```

Now I can define some TikZ styles. The `every fill in box` defines some basics …

```
\tikzset{
   every fill in box/.style={
     inner xsep=0pt,
     minimum height=3ex,
     align=center,
     font={\sffamily\slshape},
   },
```

… and the next styles define various appearances for the fill in boxes.

```
   ...
```

The last style, is a dummy that can be used to change the style easily.

```
   fill in/.style={
      colored box,
   },
}
```

Now I need a helper macro that either hides or shows the solution …

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \fib@hide } ...
```

… and one to print the box with the desired style:

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \fib@makebox } ...
```

Now I got everything to define `\fib` (*“fill in box”*). It will have a starred version to always print the solution, an optional argument to change the style locally and the mandatory argument taking the content of the fill in box. Depending on the star (stored as bool in `#1`) the solution hiding is set to false. If theres an optional argument (`\IfValueT{#2}`) the style is redefined. Then it must be testest if the macro is in math mode (`\ifmmode` = true) or in text mode (`\ifmmode` = false). If the macro is inside math the current style must be checked and handled with `\mathchoice`.

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \fib } ...
```

Last thing to do is to deactivate the `@`:

```
\makeatother
```

Comment: Impressive work, @Tobi! Many thanks! Is it also possible to replicate [the picture from my main post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SU0fx.png)? BTW, I just tested your functions with Beamer and `\only<>`, and it is fantasic! I can show one slide without the solutions and the next slide with all filled in :) I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Your welcome. See my edit for the bracket style … I just hat my old math books in mind and forget about your desired style O:-)

Comment: I added some rudimentary support for `beamer`’s `<>` overlay syntax

Comment: Thanks for the update and improvements! It works brilliant.

Answer (score 11):

### With an optional argument

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand\ph[2][1em]{%
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\rule{.5pt}{3pt}\rule{#1}{.5pt}\rule{.5pt}{3pt}}%
    \hspace{-.5\dimexpr#1+1pt\relax}\clap{#2}\hspace{.5\dimexpr#1+1pt\relax}}

\begin{document}
$1+\ph{}=3$, find $\ph[2em]{}$. Answer $\ph[3em]{2}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've just found a more elegant solution: `\newdimen{\phWidth}%    
\newcommand\phAutoWidth[1]{%
    \setlength{\phWidth}{\widthof{#1}}%
    \ph[\phWidth]{#1}}`. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ComFreek: for this you can use the shorter `\settowidth{\phWidth}{#1}` ...

Comment: @Tobi `\newcommand\phAutoWidth[1]{%
    \settowidth{\phWidth}{#1}}` does not display anything.

Comment: @ComFreek: It shouldn’Td display anything – it just sets the value of the length `\phWidth` to the width of the second argument (the content of `#1` here) ;-) So `\settowidth{\phWidth}{#1}` is a shortcut for `\setlength{\phWidth}{\widthof{#1}}` not for the whole definition, which must be `\newcommand\phAutoWidth[1]{\settowidth{\phWidth}{#1}\ph[\phWidth]{#1}}` then.

Answer (score 8):

(very) light-weight method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ph}{\texttt{\char32 }}

\begin{document}
$1+\ph=3$, find $\ph$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: placeholder]

I felt bad about not having used `\textvisiblespace`. And here comes something funny, in `OT1` encoding, `\textvisiblespace` is actually done using rules:

> ```
> \OT1\textvisiblespace ->\mbox {\kern .06em\vrule \@height .3ex}%
>                           \vbox {\hrule \@ width .3em}\hbox {\vrule \@height .3ex}
> ```

But in `T1` encoding, it is the same as `\char32` as used above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ph}{\texttt{\textvisiblespace}}

\begin{document}

% \showoutput

$\texttt{\char32}\neq\textvisiblespace$ in encoding OT1.

{\usefont{T1}{cmtt}{m}{n}\char32}${}={}${\usefont{T1}{cmtt}{m}{n}\textvisiblespace}
in encoding T1.

\end{document}
```

> [image: placeholder2]

Comment: +1 thanks for your research. It's quite interesting that OT1 doesn't use a normal space while T1 does.