# Lining up boxes using different fonts

Tags: boxes, baseline

I am writing a math quiz that uses cloze questions: questions with a missing number that has to be determined.

To accommodate the handwriting of students, I'm creating an answer box using `\fbox{\huge\phantom{NN}}`.

These are elementary math facts, like 3 + 5 = 8. There are three possibilities: The first item could be missing ([missing] + 5 = 8), the second could be missing (3 + [missing] = 8), or the answer could be missing (3 + 5 = [missing]).

These are vertically aligned math problems that use an `\hrule` to separate the first two terms from the answer (think elementary math).  I am trying to line up the problems so that the various components line up.

I am using `\LARGE` font (`\baselineskip = 22 pt`) for the numerals and `\huge` (`\baselineskip = 25 pt`) for the blank answer square. I tried to line these up by adding additional `\vspace{3pt}`, but it isn't working quite right.

Using the input below:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\def\clozeMiddle[#1][#2][#3]{
\hbox to 72pt{
\vbox{
\vspace{3pt}
\hbox to 46pt{\hfill#1}
\vspace{1pt}
\hbox{\hbox to 12pt{\hfill#3}\hbox to 34pt{\hfill\fbox{\vbox{\huge\phantom{NN}}}}}
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule\vspace{2pt}\vspace{3pt}\hbox to 46pt{\hfill#2}}
}
}

\def\clozeBottom[#1][#2][#3]{
\hbox to 72pt{
\vbox{
\vspace{3pt}
\hbox to 46pt{\hfill#1}
\vspace{1pt}
\vspace{3pt}
\hbox{\hbox to 12pt{\hfill#3}\hbox to 34pt{\hfill#2}}
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule\vspace{2pt}\hbox to 46pt{\hfill\fbox{\vbox{\huge\phantom{NN}}}}}
}
}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\hbox{
\clozeMiddle[4][7][+]
\clozeBottom[4][3][+]
}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image: Output]

The `\hrule` for the first item **almost** matches up with the `\hrule` for the second, but not quite. I think this is just because the `\fbox` line has some width.

The real issue is that the 4 in the second question is much higher the 4 in the first. I would not expect this to be the case because in both cases there should be 2 + 25 + 1 = 28 points between the `\hrule` and the bottom of the box housing the 4.

Comment: Welcome! Please put your code fragments together into a complete document so that we can copy-paste and compile your code to see exactly what you're seeing. To upload a picture, use the picture icon in the post editor, select a file, OK it and add a textual description. Your picture may not show up if you don't have enough reputation, but if you leave it as is, it will be very easy for somebody else to 'activate' it this way.

Comment: Since you seem to be using LaTeX, have you looked at packages which do this kind of thing for you? There are quite a number of packages for both maths and exams/quizzes. Not all of the maths is designed for university level, either. I believe there are packages designed for work with less advanced students, too.

Comment: Thanks, cfr for the welcome! I've modified my question and uploaded an image. I'll look into some packages, but I think I am close to having everything I need once I get this one issue sorted, as I can just tile the page as necessary with these boxes.

Comment: Maybe worth a look too: [Graphical placeholder for “variables”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148026/4918) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of non-latex commands in the definitions, and the resulting command doesn't follow normal latex syntax as it has mandatory arguments in `[]`.
(and using unguarded `\hbox` in latex has odd effects if you try to centre it or start a paragraph, or make it the first thing after a section heading, etc.

A more idiomatic latex version might be

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\newcommand\clozeMiddle[3]{{%
\LARGE\setlength\extrarowheight{20pt}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
&\makebox(72,30)[r]{#1}\\
\makebox(10,30){$#3$}&\framebox(72,30)[r]{}\\
\hline
&\makebox(72,30)[r]{#2}
\end{tabular}}}

\newcommand\clozeBottom[3]{{%
\LARGE\setlength\extrarowheight{20pt}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
&\makebox(72,30)[r]{#1}\\
\makebox(10,30){$#3$}&\makebox(72,30)[r]{#2}\\
\hline
&\framebox(72,30)[r]{}
\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\clozeMiddle{4}{7}{+}%
\qquad
\clozeBottom{4}{3}{+}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, David! (It was interesting to see you posting a solution here---I'm more used to see you on the xml-dev list-serv).

Comment: @DavidR I've been posting tex answers since long before xml existed:-)